# Inconsistent behavior with extra backslash in chat markdown

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

For a while I have a [Stack Exchange chat bot](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga?tab=profile) that does many things, one of the things is to post messages [like this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30130516/history)

`\[[**retailcoder/Rubberduck**](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck)\] 19 commits. 745 additions. 451 deletions.`

Which is shown in chat as:

> [[**retailcoder/Rubberduck**](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck)] 19 commits. 745 additions. 451 deletions.

However, after a while I got quite confused that for [some messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30130540/history), it **showed an extra `\` after the repository name** so that it looked like below:

`\[[**Vogel612/TranslationHelper**](https://github.com/Vogel612/TranslationHelper)\] 3 commits. 2 issue comments. 41 additions. 24 deletions.`

> [[**Vogel612/TranslationHelper**](https://github.com/Vogel612/TranslationHelper)\] 3 commits. 2 issue comments. 41 additions. 24 deletions.

*(chat markdown and site markdown behaves differently here. Here on site I added an extra `\` to make it display what chat displays)*

For a long while I thought that the problem was in the data from Github that was sent to my webhook. I looked at the data in Github but did not find any error. And then today I [noticed the same behavior](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30331259/history), but this time from my Jenkins machine:

`**\[[minesweeper-plugin1](http://stats.zomis.net:53654/job/minesweeper-plugin1/)\]** **[build 2](http://stats.zomis.net:53654/job/minesweeper-plugin1/2/)** Started`

> **[[minesweeper-plugin1](http://stats.zomis.net:53654/job/minesweeper-plugin1/)\]** **[build 2](http://stats.zomis.net:53654/job/minesweeper-plugin1/2/)** Started

Please note that [other](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30331948/history) [Jenkins](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30331098/history) [messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/30331045/history) works just fine, and do not show the extra backslash.

**What causes this inconsistent behavior? Why is there an extra `\` showing on some messages but not all?**

Note: I tagged this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because of the inconsistent behavior. I know that I can just replace `)\]` with `)]` in the messages and it will display correctly, but this question is about why it is shown differently, not about how to make it show correctly.

Comment: We did a lot of testing from this message on : http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30408716#30408716 . There are a lot of messages to reproduce the problems and try different things. (We are a bit "obsess" with the bug :P )